# Composer autoload is called but loaded nothing

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

### Project structure

```
/Test
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    index.php
    nfe.xml
    vendor/
        autoload.php
        (more files)
```

### PHP Code

And I am trying a snipped which I found at the library's README on github

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// var_dump( get_declared_classes() );
echo 'a';
$nfeProc = NFePHPSerialize::xmlToObject(file_get_contents('nfe.xml'));
echo 'b';

//Capturando CNPJ do emitente
$cnpjEmitente = $nfeProc->getNFe()->getInfNFe()->getEmit()->getCNPJ();

echo $cnpjEmitente;
```

### Results

But I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'NFePHPSerialize' not found in /var/www/html/Test/index.php on line 7
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/Test/index.php:0
```

Finally I have uncommented the `var_dump( get_declared_classes() );` just to know whether something from the library [nfephp-serialize](https://github.com/jansenfelipe/nfephp-serialize) (for tax purposes) is loaded but I found nothing.

### Initialization

To init the `Test` directory, I have issued the following command:

```
$ composer require jansenfelipe/nfephp-serialize
```

Comment: use the `use` PHP statement to "use" the class you would like, as in `use Slim/App;` or prepend the namespace when using `NFePHPSerialize` (you would find it in NFePHPSerialize sources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to solve?

What is missing is the path associated with the `NFePHPSerialize` class. It is `JansenFelipe\NFePHPSerialize`.

You may want to `use` the class `NFePHPSerialize` with its namespace, as so:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use JansenFelipe\NFePHPSerialize\NFePHPSerialize;
```

or simply write:

```
$nfeProc = JansenFelipe\NFePHPSerialize\NFePHPSerialize::xmlToObject(file_get_contents('nfe.xml'));
```

### How I found the namespace?

You may want to search for the `NFePHPSerialize` class in the `/vendor` directory... and find the `namespace` statement, which is:

```
namespace JansenFelipe\NFePHPSerialize;
```

So, the class is available with `namespace\class` as so:

```
$var = new JansenFelipe\NFePHPSerialize\NFePHPSerialize(...);
```

But you can improve this by inserting the `use` statement as so:

```
<?php

use JansenFelipe\NFePHPSerialize\NFePHPSerialize;

// some code...

$var = new NFePHPSerialize(...);
```

I hope this helps you! :)

Comment: That's right, so, `get_declared_classes` are not very useful, because I have printed the classes and there was nothing I was looking for, even though they were actually being loaded...

Comment: in a way, you may always want to read a bit the source code you use, then you will know which class are downloaded in the vendor/ directory, be able to use the right class at the right moment and also know how to access to it; this is more reliable than a documentation but it is less readable